# Must Laravel and React be separated?

Tags: laravel, reactjs

I am a very beginner with React.

I want to use Laravel with React. And I have a doubt with the **csrf_token** and the structure of the 2 projects.

I see 2 solutions :

- I develop the React app into the Laravel folders. And in this case I can write a csrf_token somewhere into my html page which will contain the React app. And then the react app can make all the POST I want to the Laravel server with this token.
- I separate the two apps : one Laravel server somewhere. And the React app somewhere else. Each of them has their own development folders.

In the two cases, I will use API between Laravel server and React app.

**Question 1** : I read that a good practice is to separate the Laravel back end from the React front end. But in this case, how the React app can know the csrf_token ?

**Question 2** : perhaps this csrf_token is not necessary in the case where the "React" app use api from the "Laravel" server ?

As you see I am confused with this csrf_token in this situation.

Comment: Will they be on the same domain or do you intend to have your API on a different (sub)domain? If they will be on the same domain I suggest having them in the same project for starting convenience sake, it's easy to separate them later on if you'll need to. If they will be hosted on different domains I would go with separating them from the start, as it will be easier to setup hosting environment.

Comment: As for the CSRF, if you have separate domains you won't use CSRF anyway. And if you won't it will be easier to reason about where the CSRF token comes from if you have frontend and backend in the same project. But if you separate the projects you can still get it from the HTML meta tag just the way you would otherwise.

Comment: Thanks devk for your replies. But if the back and front are separated, then I really don't see how this csrf_token can be used in the front . Because this token is supplied by the back in the index.html

Comment: Yeah the more I think about it, I believe that you'll have a much harder time setting everything up if you separate them. You could still symlink or edit apache/nginx configuration to serve the separated project from another folder and get the CSRF token from the cookie/headers that Laravel sends. But it'll take more effort to set it up. But of course, CSRF only matters if your app's authentication is based on sessions. Which with SPAs it often isn't. Up to you and your application how you set things up really.

Comment: thanks devk for your feedback. For the moment, as a react beginner I will start "easy" : I won't separate front and back. Have a nice day. Dom